# Is it possible to use bare-metal XenServer's virtual machines on the same computer and how?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, xen, bare-metal, xenserver

Can I install XenServer on a machine as a bare-metal installation and create and use its virtual machines on the same machine or I need to use the VMs with XenClient over a network connection? I mean something like VMware player without a host machine.

Comment: Nice question, I'm curious tow, so is it possible?